# Function to query different time series in R with vector as input

Tags: sql, r, odbc, dbi, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I was getting the min a max dates for an specific time series within a database fact table as follows:

```r
auxiliar.dates <- function(machine, signal) {
  q.Aux1 <- paste("SELECT
         t1.machine,
       t1.signal,
       t2.signal_name,
       t1.min_snsr_dt,
       t1.max_snsr_dt,
       t1.min_snsr_ts,
       t1.max_snsr_ts,
       t1.min_etl_dt,
       t1.max_etl_dt,
       t1.rec_cnt
       FROM ", config$SF_CONFIG$my_schema_name1, ".mytable1 AS t1 
       LEFT JOIN ", config$SF_CONFIG$my_schema_name1, ".mytable2", "AS t2
       ON t1.signal=t2.signal 
       WHERE t1.unit_key=")
  q.Aux2 <- " AND t1.signal="
  q.Aux.final <- str_c(q.Aux1, machine, q.Aux2, signal)
  res <- dbSendQuery(myConn, q.Aux.final)
  df <- as.data.table(dbFetch(res, n=-1))
  dbClearResult(res)
  return(df)
}

dates <-auxiliar.dates("machine", "signal")
```

The output of this functions is a data table as follows:

[image]

Then I was using the output to query the specific signal between min and max ts as follows:

```r
signalQuery <- function(machine, signal, min_ts, max_ts) {

  q1.aux1 <- paste("SELECT snsr_val, 
                      snsr_ts, 
                      snsr_dt, 
                      signal,
                      qual, 
                      machine 
                      FROM ", config$SF_CONFIG$schema_name1, 
                     ".mytable1 AS v
                      WHERE machine=", sep="")

  q3.aux1 <-paste(" AND signal=", signal, " AND snsr_ts BETWEEN ", "'", min_ts, "'",
                    " AND ", "'", max_ts, "'", " ORDER BY v.snsr_ts", sep = "")

  qt.auxtotal <- str_c(q1.aux1,
                     machine,
                     q3.aux1) #we join que full query with stringr library

  res <- dbSendQuery(myConn, qt.auxtotal)
  df <- as.data.table(dbFetch(res,n=-1))
  dbClearResult(res) #cleaning memory
  return(df)
}
```

To call signal 71 for instance I was doing:

```r
    signal71.dates <- auxiliar.dates(machine, 71)
    df   <- signalQuery(machine, 71, signal71.dates$min_snsr_dt, signal71.dates$max_snsr_dt)
```

In case that I need to query more signals I was doing exactly the same procedure but I was taking the min value of max_snsr_dt of my dataframes call signal_number.dates and the max value of the min_snsr_dt of my dataframes signal_number.dates.

I would like know to change a bit the process and being able to input a vector which the signals that I want in both auxiliar.dates and signalQuery function.

My first trial was to modify auxiliar.dates:

```r
q.Aux2 <- " AND t1.signal="
```

to:

```r
q.Aux2 <- " AND t1.signal IN ("
q.Aux.final <- str_c(q.Aux1, machine, q.Aux2, paste(signal, ")", sep = ""))
```

However when I call the function as:

```r
test <- auxiliar.dates(984, c(70,71))
```

I get the following error:

> Error in new_result(connection@ptr, statement) :    Expecting a
>   single string value: [type=character; extent=2].

Will someone be able to support?

BR

Comment: Since nobody will be able to reproduce this themselves, I think your best bet might be to `debug(auxiliar.dates)` and then run it with those arguments, then before `dbSendQuery`, look at the arguments you are sending to it (`myConn` and `qt.auxtotal`) ... that might be okay. From there, look at `res` and see if it makes sense (it should be of type `<OdbcResult>`).

Comment: A word of advice: you have at least two instances of scope-breach: using variables that are assumed to be available in the parent frame (or its parents). While I understand why, this will be bad for reproducibility, testing, and sending functions to colleagues who might not have the same global or parent environment. I suggest you make `config` and `con` literal arguments of your function and use them.

Comment: @r2evans

I will try with the debug. Regarding the scope-breach you are quite right to point this out. I will try to include it in the next refactoring.

Comment: @Parfait

I am using odbc and DBI. The DBMS is Snowflake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following changes:

- **Parameterization**: Avoid too many string concatenation that impairs readability and maintainability. Instead use parameterization which is supported in `DBI` + `odbc` with [`sqlInterpolate`](https://db.rstudio.com/best-practices/run-queries-safely/). Ideally, you would hard code the table names in the SQL string statement but since identifiers cannot be parameterized, `paste` (or `paste0` for no spaces between) will still have to be used.
- **Single SQL query**: Combine the two SQL queries using a [Common Table Expression (CTE)](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/queries-cte.html) which is supported in Snowflake. Specifically, first query is joined to last query by *machine* and *signal* and date `BETWEEN` interval. In turn, you combine both functions, reduce number of database trips, and avoid intermediate, helper objects.
- **Use `dbGetQuery`**: If data load is not an issue with need to fetch large result sets by chunks, use `dbGetQuery` to combine the `dbSendQuery` and `dbFetch` steps for concision.
- **Function inputs**: As @r2evans comments, avoid relying on environment variables of unknown parent sources to be situated inside a local function. Instead, pass all needed input parameters for local scoped variables.
- **Iteration**: Because these functions use scalar parameters, you must iterate through values such as with `lapply` to run functions multiple times and then row bind results for final data table.

**Single Function**

```
signalQuery <- function(my_schema, machine, signal) { 
    # PREPARED STATEMENT 
    sql <- paste0("WITH sub AS 
                     (SELECT t1.machine, t1.signal,  t2.signal_name, 
                             t1.min_snsr_dt, t1.max_snsr_dt,
                             t1.min_snsr_ts, t1.max_snsr_ts, 
                             t1.min_etl_dt,  t1.max_etl_dt, t1.rec_cnt
                      FROM ", my_schema, ".mytable1 AS t1 
                      LEFT JOIN ", my_schema, ".mytable2", "AS t2
                          ON t1.signal = t2.signal 
                      WHERE t1.unit_key = ?m_param AND t1.signal= ?s_param)

                   SELECT v.snsr_val, v.snsr_ts, v.snsr_dt, v.signal, 
                          v.qual, v.machine 
                   FROM ", my_schema, ".mytable1 AS v
                   INNER JOIN sub
                     ON v.machine = sub.machine
                     AND v.signal = sub.signal
                     AND v.snsr_ts BETWEEN sub.min_snsr_dt AND sub.max_snsr_dt
                   ORDER BY v.snsr_ts")

    # BIND PARAMS TO ?MARK PLACEHOLDERS
    query <- sqlInterpolate(conn, sql, m_param = machine, s_param = signal)

    # RUN QUERY
    dt <- as.data.table(dbGetQuery(myConn, query))

    return(dt)    
}
```

**Function Calls**

```
# SINGLE SIGNAL VALUE
q.Aux.final <- signalQuery(myschema = config$SF_CONFIG$my_schema_name1,
                           machine = 984, signal = 70)

# MULTIPLE SIGNAL VALUES
dt_list <- lapply(c(70,71), function(i) 
                    signalQuery(myschema = config$SF_CONFIG$my_schema_name1,
                                machine = 984, signal = i)
           )

q.Aux.final <- data.table::rbindlist(dt_list)
```

---

**Multiple Functions**

In case, you do need the first resultset for analytical needs, continue with same process without CTE:

```
auxiliar.dates <- function(my_schema, machine, signal) { 

    sql <- paste0("SELECT t1.machine, t1.signal,  t2.signal_name, 
                          t1.min_snsr_dt, t1.max_snsr_dt,
                          t1.min_snsr_ts, t1.max_snsr_ts, 
                          t1.min_etl_dt,  t1.max_etl_dt, t1.rec_cnt
                   FROM ", my_schema, ".mytable1 AS t1 
                   LEFT JOIN ", my_schema, ".mytable2", "AS t2
                         ON t1.signal=t2.signal 
                   WHERE t1.unit_key = ?m_param AND t1.signal= ?s_param")

    query <- sqlInterpolate(conn, sql, m_param = machine, s_param = signal)
    dt <- as.data.table(dbGetQuery(myConn, query))

    return(dt)    
}


signalQuery <- function(my_schema, machine, signal, min_ts, max_ts) {

    sql <- paste0("SELECT v.snsr_val, v.snsr_ts, v.snsr_dt, v.signal, 
                          v.qual, v.machine 
                   FROM ", my_schema, ".mytable1 AS v
                   WHERE v.machine = ?m_param
                     AND v.signal = ?s_param
                     AND v.snsr_ts BETWEEN ?min_ts_prm AND ?max_ts_prm
                   ORDER BY v.snsr_ts")

    query <- sqlInterpolate(conn, sql, m_param = machine, s_param = signal,
                            min_ts_prm = min_ts, max_ts_prm = max_ts)
    dt <- as.data.table(dbGetQuery(myConn, query))

    return(dt)    
}
```

**Function Calls**

```
# SINGLE SIGNAL VALUE
signal71.dates <- auxiliar.dates(config$SF_CONFIG$my_schema_name1, 984, 71)

q.Aux.final <- signalQuery(config$SF_CONFIG$my_schema_name1, 984, 71,
                           signal71.dates$min_snsr_dt, signal71.dates$max_snsr_dt)

# MULTIPLE SIGNAL VALUES
dt_list <- lapply(c(70,71), function(i) 
                    signalQuery(myschema = config$SF_CONFIG$my_schema_name1,
                                machine = 984, signal = i)
           )

signal.dates_dt <- data.table::rbindlist(dt_list)


dt_list <- lapply(1:nrow(signal.dates_dt), function(i) 
                    signalQuery(myschema = config$SF_CONFIG$my_schema_name1,
                                machine  = signal.dates_dt$machine[i], 
                                signal   = signal.dates_dt$signal[i],
                                min_ts   = signal.dates$min_snsr_dt[i],
                                max_ts   = signal.dates$max_snsr_dt[i])
           )

q.Aux.final <- data.table::rbindlist(dt_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update: error solved, the connector expired I need it to connect again**

Really appreciate your solution. However I am getting and error whenever as use as input two schemas.

```
auxiliar.dates <- function(connection, my_schema1, my_schema2, machine, signal) { 

  sql <- paste0("SELECT t1.machine, t1.signal,  t2.signal_name, 
                          t1.min_snsr_dt, t1.max_snsr_dt,
                          t1.min_snsr_ts, t1.max_snsr_ts, 
                          t1.min_etl_dt,  t1.max_etl_dt, t1.rec_cnt
                   FROM ", my_schema1, ".table1 AS t1 
                   LEFT JOIN ", my_schema2, ".table2", " AS t2
                         ON t1.snsr_key = t2.snsr_key
                   WHERE t1.machine = ?m_param AND t1.signal = ?s_param")

  query <- sqlInterpolate(connection, sql, m_param = machine, s_param = signal)
  dt <- as.data.table(dbGetQuery(connection, query))

  return(dt)    
}`
```

However I get the follwing error:

```
 signal1.dates <- auxiliar.dates(myConn, config$SF_CONFIG$my_schema1, config$SF_CONFIG$my_schema2, machine.number, signal.number)
 Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘sqlInterpolate’ for signature ‘"Snowflake"’
```

Do you know why this is happening? When I try with only one input and not specifying the connection as part of the function it just works fine.